# Replace by previous values

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I have some dataframe like the one shown above. The goal of this program is to replace some specific value by the previous one.

```
import pandas as pd
test = pd.DataFrame([2,2,3,1,1,2,4,6,43,23,4,1,3,3,1,1,1,4,5], columns = ['A'])
```

obtaining:

[image]

If one want to replace all *1* by the previous values, a possible solution is:

```
for li in test[test['A'] == 1].index:
    test['A'].iloc[li] = test['A'].iloc[li-1]
```

[image]

However, it is very inefficient. Can you suggest a more efficient solution?

Comment: If you look carefully, I leave the code and not an image of the code. I post an image of the output, that is quite different.

Comment: I did look carefully, and while its pedantically not the same, it falls into the same category with the same issue. I should be able to copy-paste those inputs directly into my editor to help **you** solve this problem. *When you force us to transcribe an image, you waste everyone's time.*

Comment: Did you read the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, `replace` to `np.nan` then `ffill`

```
test.replace(1,np.nan).ffill().astype(int)
Out[881]: 
     A
0    2
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    3
5    2
6    4
7    6
8   43
9   23
10   4
11   4
12   3
13   3
14   3
15   3
16   3
17   4
18   5
```